# Hand rig not deforming properly

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

After watching about 20 rigging tutorials is till can't figure it out,
I've already created the bones but I just need to parent them and that's the part I cant figure out. Can someone who does know how to do it make a simple rig out of it and send it to me so i can use it and finally understand it?
My blend file can be found here: [File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o964w8uxe4qnseg/Arms.blend?dl=0)
[image]

Comment: I've checked your file and it looks okay to me as all bones move nicely and connected, what's the problem in it?

Comment: The mesh stretches out and takes other pieces of mesh with it, i don't know if i did something wrong or if its a problem with my mesh

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot and highlight the problem?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yw57hkeb3n6sk8u/Arms.PNG?dl=0 , I don't think this should happen.

Comment: why you removed my edits? the current state of the question won't allow users to help you

Comment: I still need help btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select your mesh and hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then choose `Clear Parent`
2. Delete all vertex groups
   [image]
3. Enter Edit mode and select all using <kbd>P</kbd> then hit the <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> and write `Flip Normals`
   [image]
4. Select your mesh then select your armature using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Right Click and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and choose `Automatic Weighting`
   [image]
5. Set Pivot to Median centre and now the arms and fingers will be deforming nicely
   [image]